# WPF StringFormat TextBlock text

Tags: wpf, string-formatting

I'm trying to format a string in WPF for a text block. I want to obtain something like this in my text block: `[name]`. I know to bind text block's text to the string property which I want to show but I don't know how to put the brackets. 
Can you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both of them worked :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put it in the resources as such, and then access the format in the `StringFormat` attribute of the binding.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <system:String x:Key="InBracketsFormat">[{0}]</system:String>
</Page.Resources>


<TextBlock
        Text="{Binding MyValue, StringFormat={StaticResource InBracketsFormat}}"/>
```

This method provides the advantage of reuse as well as being able to have keyword tokens (such as the `'` character) within the text for the format.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding MyProperty, StringFormat='[{0}]'}"/>
```